# calculate force between two magnets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields

I have used a couple of online calculators to estimate the attractive force between two cylindrical bar magnets. Using d=1"; t=1"; x=0.1"; Neo35 (Br=12,300 Gauss):

[source 1](http://www.magnetsales.com/design/calc_filles/PullAndPushBetween2DiscMagnets.asp) gives 63.5 lbf
[source 2](https://www.kjmagnetics.com/calculator.asp) gives 29.6 lbf

source 2 explains data is based on measured data, so this accounts for the difference from source 1. But in general, I think this is the right ballpark number.

I then tried to reproduce these numbers myself, using a formula I found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force_between_magnets#Calculating_the_magnetic_force). I could not get close to the right answer - my answer is about 4000 lbf. **Could someone please explain what I did wrong in my calculation?**

[image: formula]

[image]

**EDIT**
Tough crowd. Let me try and be more specific.

The problem itself is pretty straightforward. I did not really mean to imply I need someone to check the numbers. I mean more on if I am applying the right approach to the problem:

1. Is the formula above valid when trying to replicate results in
   the calculators I linked? (i.e. "Calculate the Pull and Repulsion
   Forces Between Two Disc Magnets")
2. Perhaps "real life" is significantly different than theory for this
   application? In which case, the engineering calculators would apply a de-rating
   factor that is not represented in the Wikipedia formula. I did find
   any references to this, but perhaps someone with more knowledge
   could advise?
3. Assuming the formula is valid here, I think Magnetic Flux Density
   (B_0) is the most likely source of my error. It is my understanding that this is a physical property of the material. Is that correct? The value I found for
   Neo35 is Br = 12,300 Gauss (CGS units). I converted this to SI 1.23
   Tesla using a 10^-4 conversion factor. Is this the correct
   interpretation of B_0?

Comment: Why the downvote? Also, this is not homework (I rolled back the edit.)

Comment: Hi Roberto. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks. In that case I now understand "homework" in this context. I still don't get the downvotes though; I clearly did some background research and attempted an answer. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In particular, the policy states, "It's not enough to just show your work and ask where you went wrong. If you just need someone to check your work, you can always seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher." Even if you aren't in school and thus can't easily confer with someone in person, the fact remains we aren't a check-my-work site. As for downvotes, each user has their reasons, but for what it's worth this has far fewer downvotes than a typical "here's my homework, do it for me" question.

Comment: @ChrisWhite - OK. Thanks for the clarification. To make it clear I am not looking for a "do it for me" response, I edited the post with specific questions.

Comment: Roberto, you really need to reformulate this as a new question just asking conceptual things.  Minor editing / additions the existing question is probably a lost cause.